# Extra <tr> when using table in datalist control

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table, datalist

I tried to using `Datalist` and Something goes wrong I cant solve it ! 
On the Output... why the extra row is created after each row??
what's my fault?

Look at my codes :

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="233px">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>InTheater</th>
            <th>Spam</th>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:DataList>`
```

Comment: What is your resulting HTML?

Comment: Ok the `th` on header, but later you need to use `td`

Comment: ok fixed them ! but not works

Comment: +1 for showing result markup + are you sure that it's not your actual data doubled?

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with this problem myself. I solved it by removing the `<tr>` in the template. So instead of

```
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>InTheater</th>
    <th>Spam</th>
</tr>
```

I used

```
<th>Id</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>InTheater</th>
<th>Spam</th>
```

I don't know why it adds the extra rows but this was the solution I found.

Posting for others looking for the answer.